# Build Error: Invalid resource directory name: "res renderers"

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Recently in my Xamarin.Forms solution, inside the Android project, I am getting the following build error:

`Invalid resource directory name: "res renderers"`

Doing a small amount of investigating I found the culprit inside the obj>Debug>res> folder. I tried deleting the folder and rebuilding but it seems to recreate it every time. I'm not sure why it started doing this and causing the [IDE006](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Diagnosing-Project-System-Build-Errors) warning as well.

Anyone know how to remedy this? Is there a way to configure the Android project to ignore this folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an `.axml` file inside my Android project that was causing the `res/renderers` file to be created that contained I suppose a corresponding file. Due to that creation I was getting the error but upon deleting the `.axml` file in my project, cleaning and rebuilding, the res/renderers folder stopped being created on build. I had that `.axml` file created before and not cause this error so I'm not completely convinced this is the real answer but it solved my problem and hopefully when I recreate the file it doesn't happen again. Perhaps use of a regular `.xml` would be better.

Comment: This was really helpful! I got a Invalid resource directory name: "res menu" error when building my solution and rebuilding my .xaml fixed the issue!

Comment: @Baxorr excellent! It's quite a sneaky issue for sure. Please upvote the answer so others can see :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did the two followings to solve:

1. try clean/build solution several times (after few times it worked for me)
2. exit and come back.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just the Droid project or the whole solution?

Comment: I am not sure how your setup is but try with the project first.

Comment: Not really working unfortunately, would be a nice fix but oh well. Very perplexing why this is happening all of the sudden. All I did was open my project in VS 2017 to see how it was (I usually work in VS 2015) and it broke it :(

Comment: I also tried deleting the res after each build so give it a go with trying to delete the folder each time

Comment: After several tries, it let me delete the folder. I don't know why it happens but that is how I fixed everytime.

Comment: Questionable fix found. Refer to my answer if interested ^^^